Permissions Not Visible in SharePoint Document Library Files Despite Being Set via Microsoft Graph API
I’m working on a C# application using the Microsoft Graph API version 4.51.0 to manage permissions in a SharePoint site’s document library Files. The code successfully sets permissions programmatically, we also getting destination permission id as response but the changes are not reflected when checking the permissions in the SharePoint UI.
Here’s the code I’m using to set the permissions:
IDriveItemInviteRequest permissionRequest = SelectedDrive.Items[DestinationDriveId] .Invite(destinationUserPermissions, true, destinationPermissionRoles, false, null) .Request(); 
IDriveItemInviteCollectionPage invites = MicrosoftHelper.InvokeApiCall(() => { return permissionRequest.PostAsync().Result; }, this);

SelectedDrive and DestinationDriveId are correctly initialized.
destinationUserPermissions is a list of recipients (emails).
destinationPermissionRoles contains roles like "write" or "read".
MicrosoftHelper.InvokeApiCall is a helper to handle API calls and exceptions.
The issue:
The API response indicates that permissions are being applied successfully (no errors or exceptions). However, when I check the SharePoint document library permissions in the UI, the changes are not visible.
Tried :-

Verified that the destination drive and item IDs are correct.
Checked for any caching or propagation delays, but the issue persists.
Reviewed the roles and recipients to ensure they are valid.

Expecting :-
Permission should be visible on UI.
